# How to access Windows.​Services.​Store from an older Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-store

I'm looking for a way to access the [Windows.Services.Store Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store) from a Win32 Delphi project that is converted to a UWP app using the [Windows Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop).

I found a similar question about accessing the namespace using C++: [How to access Windows.Services.Store namespace from a Win32 app converted to UWP with the "Project Centennial converter" to enable in-app purchases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758729/how-to-access-windows-services-store-namespace-from-a-win32-app-converted-to-uwp)

It requires the file `Windows.Services.Store.h` which can be found inside the Windows SDK. There is also a corresponding [IDL file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa367062(v=vs.85).aspx). I tried several tools to convert on of these files to Delphi but they all failed to parse them.

I'm on Delphi 10 Berlin.

Is there a different way to access `Windows.Services.Store`?

Comment: This UWP/WDB SDK is part of the latest Delphi 10.2 release, IIRC. Have you this version?

Comment: I'm on Delphi 10 Berlin.

Comment: Upgrade to 10.2 Tokyo, and you will probably find this SDK. Check https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-delphi-uwp-app-on-windows-10-store and  search for the WinRT headers via GetIt.

Comment: is it possible to use these SDKs in Delphi 7 ?