# How to access Windows.Services.Store from Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, desktop-bridge

I am selling Delphi app in Win 10 Store and like to start to use new buy in-app features. How to use Windows.Services.Store from Delphi 7 ?

Is there example code  for accessing StoreContext COM interface  ?

Comment: Not delphi, but certainly translatable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39762746/800214

Comment: there seem to be plugins for newer delphi to do this... but not for D7

Comment: you can do raw winapi from D7, what is stopping you?

Comment: sorry I am not able to translate that one

Comment: You can't ask us to [recommend or find libraries, tools or other off-site resources](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here

Answer (score 3):

You have to build a wrapper C++ component that makes the API calls into Windows.Services.Store.* APIs and exports entry points for your app to call. Then you include this component in your Delphi app package and call from your Delphi code into the exported entry points.

I don't have a Delphi 7 sample available, but here is a sample that is applying the same concept with a VB6 app:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/VB6withXaml